# Tracking property changes with PostSharp

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, postsharp, .net-4.7.2

I would like to enable a given wizard page when all preceding pages are valid. Here is my view model:

```
[Aggregatable]
[NotifyPropertyChanged]
[ContentProperty("Pages")]
public class Wizard
{
    [Child, AggregateAllChanges] 
    public AdvisableCollection<Page> Pages { get; } = new AdvisableCollection<Page>();
}
```

Here is the `Page` itself:

```
[Aggregatable]
[NotifyPropertyChanged]
public class Page : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    [Parent] Wizard Wizard { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Valid { get; set; }

    [SafeForDependencyAnalysis]
    public bool Enabled
    {
        get
        {
            if(Depends.Guard)
                Depends.On(Wizard.Pages);

            return Wizard.Pages
                .TakeWhile(p => p != this)
                .All(p => p.Valid);
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };
    void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        if (Wizard != null)
            NotifyPropertyChangedServices.SignalPropertyChanged(Wizard, nameof(Wizard.Pages));
    }
}
```

I was expecting PostSharp to notify about `Enabled` property change when `Wizard.Pages` changes. It does not work unfortunately – there is no updates to `Enabled` properties. What is wrong about this code?

XAML to test:

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:Wizard>
        <local:Page Name="First"/>
        <local:Page Name="Second"/>
        <local:Page Name="Third"/>
        <local:Page Name="Forth"/>
    </local:Wizard>
</Window.DataContext>
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Pages}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Page}">
            <CheckBox Content="{Binding Name}" IsChecked="{Binding Valid}" IsEnabled="{Binding Enabled}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: The compatibility bug between the `NotifyPropertyChanged` and `Aggregatable` aspects has been fixed in PostSharp version 6.0.29. Please update your NuGet packages to the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

We have investigated the provided sample and it looks like the cause is a compatibility issue between the `NotifyPropertyChanged` and `Aggregatable` aspects.

If you remove or comment out the `[Aggregatable]` attributes, then the event is raised for the `Enabled` property as expected. Actually, it's even enough to mark the `Wizard` property as a reference instead of parent to fix the NPC behavior. Once the `Wizard` property is not marked as a parent, you'll need to ensure the correct value by setting the property manually.

Please note, that you also need to add a property name check in the `OnPropertyChanged` method to avoid the infinite loop "Wizard.Pages changed" -> "Enabled changed" -> "Wizard.Pages changed"...

```
[Aggregatable]
[NotifyPropertyChanged]
public class Page : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    //[Parent]
    [Reference]
    public Wizard Wizard { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Valid { get; set; }

    [SafeForDependencyAnalysis]
    public bool Enabled
    {
        get
        {
            if ( Depends.Guard )
                Depends.On( Wizard.Pages );

            return Wizard.Pages
                .TakeWhile( p => p != this )
                .All( p => p.Valid );
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };
    void OnPropertyChanged( string propertyName )
    {
        PropertyChanged( this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs( propertyName ) );
        if ( Wizard != null && propertyName != nameof( Enabled ) )
            NotifyPropertyChangedServices.SignalPropertyChanged( Wizard, nameof( Wizard.Pages ) );
    }
}
```

We'll continue investigating the issue and we'll update the answer once the fix is released.

**UPDATE.** The compatibility bug between the `NotifyPropertyChanged` and `Aggregatable` aspects has been fixed in PostSharp version 6.0.29. Please update your NuGet packages to the latest version.