# Parent property setting interception in PostSharp

Tags: c#, postsharp, .net-4.7.2

How to be notified that item parent property has been set when we add aggregate to `AdvisableCollection` (PostSharp)? I would like to setup in constructor an outside world property change observer (Gu.Reactive) but there is no way to figure out that `Parent` property is updated. `[NotifyParentChanged]` ignores Parent properties.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tracking property changes with PostSharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52359967/tracking-property-changes-with-postsharp)

Answer (score 0):

This use case is currently affected by the compatibility issue between `NotifyPropertyChanged` and `Aggregatable` aspects. We are investigating the issue and we'll update the related discussion here on StackOverflow:

[Tracking property changes with PostSharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52359967/tracking-property-changes-with-postsharp)